# conversion from Xamarin.forms.ImageSource to UIKit.ImageView

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting this error while trying to pick a picture from gallery and assign it to an ImageView on an iOS app in Xamarin.

> cannot implicitly convert type from 'Xamarin.forms.ImageSource' to 'UIKit.ImageView'

Code :

```
ImageViewCtrl.Image= ImageSource.FromStream(() => { 
var stream = file.GetStream();
file.Dispose(); 
return stream; });
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Share your code so i know what exactly you are trying to do here

Comment: ImageViewCtrl.Image= ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;
            });

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow kindly read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also update the code to your answer and not just link causing the error but the lines above and below

Comment: The thing is that
- I am using a Designer and created ImageView to display the images picked from the gallery
- When i am trying to assign the picked image from the gallery to the ImageView, it is telling me that the implicit conversion is not possible

Comment: Show the code where you get it and then assign it to the imageview

Comment: Why does `ImageSource` appear in ios project? Are you using a Custom renderer ? Can you attach more code ?

Comment: I just want to assign the image coming from the stream (picked from gallery) to my ImageView display it. 
But ImageView doesnt support "Source", i have treid to cast it but it doesnt work